# xslt umbraco select of nodes of type

Tags: xslt, select, umbraco, nodes

I copies a calendar from one of the starter kits in umbraco. I am using the calendar in my events calendar where the structure is

```
   events page (has calendar)
      - event1
       -event2
       -event3
```

However the issue I am having is when I add a calendar macro to another page there are no events, I suspect this is because the selector is looking for child node.

I think the code is

```
 <xsl:variable name="eventsToday" select="count($currentPage//* [@isDoc and name()='Event'
```

What I really want is to select all nodes of type "event"

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
<xsl:variable name="eventsToday" select="count($currentPage//event [@isDoc]" />
```

I also use a variation of the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($rootNode)/descendant::event [@isDoc]">
  -- do something --
</xsl:for-each>
```